# Calculating centre of mass of a cylindrical wedge

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm sort of stuck with a problem. Don't know if I'm applying the theory in a wrong way. Here's the problem:

Let $S$ be the solid enclosed by the cylinder $y^2+z^2=9$ and the planes $x=0$, $y=3x$ and $z=0$ in the first octant. If this solid has a mass density function given by $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2$, compute its centre of mass.

I sketched the wedge:

[image]

I decided to use cylindrical coordinates. So I set
\begin{align}
y&=r\cos\theta,\\
z&=r\sin\theta,\\
x&=x.
\end{align}
My limits of integration are:
\begin{align}
&0\leq r\leq 3,\\
&0\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2},\\
&0\leq x\leq\frac{y}{3}=\frac{r\cos\theta}{3}.
\end{align}
To obtain the mass of the wedge:
$$\int^3_0\int^{\pi/2}_0\int^{\dfrac{r\cos\theta}{3}}_0(x^2+r^2\cos^2\theta)r \,dx\,d\theta\,dr = \frac{56}{5}.$$
Now I calculate the $x$ coordinate of the centre of mass:
$$\bar{x} = \frac{1}{\text{mass}}\int^3_0\int^{\pi/2}_0\int^{\dfrac{r\cos\theta}{3}}_0 x(x^2+r^2\cos^2\theta)r\,dx\,d\theta\,dr = \frac{5}{56}\frac{513\pi}{128}\approx 1.12 > 1.$$
Which must be wrong because the wedge goes from $x=0$ and reaches a maximum when $y=3\Rightarrow x=1$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You’ve miscalculated $\bar x$. Your answer is 3 times the correct answer.

Comment: It's a long time a ago, but may I ask how the sketch is made? Is it SquidNotes? Thank you.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin I don't remember. It was some Mac program. I know it had a ruler, I cannot remember anything else!